# React redraws all elements in the list that use the useRouter from NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my new application, I am using React and NextJS. The application has an html list element containing items that are highlighted when the page is active. When you click on an item in this list, you are taken to another page. Looking at the profiler, I noticed that all the elements of the list are redrawn, although only 2 should be
[image]

Redrawn starts in this component

```
export const SidebarOrganizationsListItemLink: React.FC<SidebarOrganizationsListItemLinkProps> = (props) => {
  const { className: classNameProp, data: { organization }, ...restProps } = props;
  const classes = useStyles()
  const router = useRouter()

  const active = React.useMemo(() => {
    const { organizationId } = router.query

    return organizationId === organization.id
  }, [router, organization.id])
  const className: string = React.useMemo(() => {
    return clsx(classes.root, { [classes.active]: active }, classNameProp)
  }, [classes, classNameProp, active])

  return (
    <ButtonLink {...restProps} className={className}>
      <Badge color="secondary" overlap="circle" badgeContent={organization.badgeContent}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>{organization.alt}</Avatar>
      </Badge>
    </ButtonLink>
  )
}
```

[Full code here](https://pastebin.com/mrPeLNgT)

Why is this happening and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping your SidebarOrganizationsList component with React.useMemo. According to the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) useMemo which will return a memoized value, but do not seem to be passing in a dependency array.

> If no array is provided, a new value will be computed on every render.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am using React.memo, not React.useMemo

Comment: in that case, any reason you can't just use React.useMemo?